# What can statistics tell us about instant runoff or ranked choice voting?

Tags: elections, voting-system

I think my most incisive retort thus far as to how Ranked Choice Voting is a bad idea, is: *Why is the second vote of the loser so much more important than that of the winners’*? If I *hypothetically* win as a third party candidate by first past the post rules, I would want to have my secondary-supporters’ winning votes for me as *their* second, too.

Comment: best of luck with your incisive retorts nick